# Contact list JQuery failing to function

Tags: php, jquery, search, hide, crud

Just started learning how to make a crud function. My create function has a radio box with three options - individual, team and company. What I want to do is upon selecting one of the options, for the fields to automatically change. E.g. individual asks for name, company, phone, email and address whereas a company would only ask for company, phone, email and address. I've got the syntax mostly done, and the forms are responsive with placing the data in mysql. It's just that the radio buttons are not responsive to showing/hiding certain forms.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
<title>Create new contact</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <form method="post" class="form-horizontal col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <h2>Motoko Insurance Contacts</h2>



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>   
<script> 
$('#contact_Type >input').change(function(){
console.log('val is '+$(this).val())
switch($(this).val()) {
case 'individual':
   $('#nameDiv').show();
   $('#companyDiv').show();
   $('#titleDiv').show();
   $('#phoneDiv').show();
   $('#emailDiv').show();
   $('#addressDiv').show();
   break;

case 'team':
   $('#nameDiv').show();
   $('#companyDiv').show();
   $('#titleDiv').hide();
   $('#phoneDiv').show();
   $('#emailDiv').show();
   $('#addressDiv').show();
   break;

case 'company':
   $('#nameDiv').hide();
   $('#companyDiv').show();
   $('#titleDiv').hide();
   $('#phoneDiv').show();
   $('#emailDiv').show();
   $('#addressDiv').show();
   break;
}
})
 </script>  

<div class="form-group">
 <label for="input" class="col-sm-2 control-label">What type of contact are you adding?</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input type="radio" name="Contact_type" value="individual" > Individual
    <input type="radio" name="Contact_type" value="team"> Team
    <input type="radio" name="Contact_type" value="company"> Company</div>
</div>



<div class="form-group">
     <label for="input1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
     <div class="col-sm-10">
         <input type="text" name="name"  class="form-control" id="input1" placeholder="Name" />
     </div>
</div>
```

Followed by the other forms for company, title, phone, email, address and closing with.

```
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary col-md-2 col-md-offset-10" value="submit" />
    </form>

    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: where is the `#nameDiv` that should be shown?

Comment: also put the js-code in a `$(function{ //your code here });` or `document.ready()`

Comment: I thought that the #namediv & show function would just let the 'name' form be in sight.

Comment: yes, but there is no 'name' form!?

Comment: <div class="form-group">
     <label for="input1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
     <div class="col-sm-10">
         <input type="text" name="name"  class="form-control" id="input1" placeholder="Name" />
     </div>
</div>

Comment: Isn't that the name form?

Comment: No. `#namediv` refers to any element with the `id` 'namediv'. So add `id="namediv"` to that `<div.....>`! (and see where it leads you to)

Comment: Doesnt change anything. I think the core problem is where the $('#contact_Type >input').change(function(){ part is located. I'm not sure where it should go.